# Why won't this draw a path?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawing

The context is that I am trying to plot a series of temperatures as a graph.

At the moment my application works as follows (as i understand it):

The application opens, openfile is used which initialises my document class this reads the modified csv file into an NSString "fileContents" which I then separate into an array of strings, each string containing the value without separaters or whitespace. As follows:

```
NSArray *temps = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n|\r"]];
```

After that I initialise my custom view, the TemperatureGraph class, and immediately pass it the array which becomes the currentlog seen in the code below. Instance id is current.

Finally I invoke:

```
[current drawpath];
```

Which is the instance method below:

```
- (void) drawpath
{
    NSBezierPath *program = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    NSPoint st = NSMakePoint(0, 0);

    [program moveToPoint:st];
    [program setLineWidth:10];
    [program setLineCapStyle:NSRoundLineCapStyle];
    [[NSColor blueColor] setStroke];
    [program stroke];

    NSUInteger a, b;
    a = [currentlog count];
    b = 0;
    while (b <= a) {
        NSPoint new;
        float x;
        x = 5 * b;

        new = NSMakePoint(x, [[currentlog objectAtIndex:b] floatValue]);
        [program lineToPoint:new];
        [program stroke];
        b += 6;
    }
}
```

Why won't it work? Definition of won't work: Application compiles and runs but I have a blank window.

Also please point out any rookie errors that are in there but don't affect code, as I am still in the learning stages here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing doesn't happen unless you have an active graphics context. I'm assuming the `drawpath` method above is inside an NSView subclass - well in there you need to override a method called `drawRect:` - it may even have been added in as a stub when you made the subclass?

Cocoa calls this method when it is time for the view to draw itself. This means that, when it is being called, a graphics context will be set up and and drawing code you do will actually appear on the screen.

Simply call your `drawpath` method from inside `drawRect:` and you should see your lines.

The general point to remember is that you don't call any drawing code yourself (except from within `drawRect:`- you either mark a view as needing display (`[myView setNeedsDisplay:YES];`, or let the system do that itself.

Comment: Thanks! So simple! So now I have the drawing working apart from the data isn't passed from my Document subclass to my custom view until after it's init method has been called. Is there a different way I should be doing this? Something like initWithData but for a View subclass?

Comment: No reason you can't just pass it in after it is initialized. This gives you the option to change the data later on as well. If you update the data, call `setNeedsDisplay:` and the view will redraw itself with the new data.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but I've now got problems with the way I'm passing the data but I guess thats another problem. Don't suppose you can tell me why this doesn't work: In NSDocument methods:

`TemperatureGraph* current = [[TemperatureGraph alloc] init]; //View Class
NSUInteger a = [temps count]; //35857 items
[current setlog:temps];
`
In TemperatureGraph.m:
`-(void)setlog:(NSArray*) log
{
    currentlog = log;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}`

This results in an array with no items?

Comment: I'd put that as another question.